# In Spark SQL How do I get persons name to show up on all rows that they are in? One they logged in and one they did not. The ID shows on both rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with an ID for each person. The ID is unique to that person. They could show up multiple time in multiple categories but from the source their name shows up as null if they have not logged in. How can I make it so that all values with a certain ID have their name show up

Small Example but there are tons of rows in the real one so I can't just choose one specific name to replace the nulls

```
| ID     | First Name| Last Name| Login| Date      |
|--------|---------- |----------|------|-----------|
|1245    |Matt       | Carter   | Yes  | 12-03-2022|
|2344    |Emily      | Seuss    | Yes  | 12-01-2022|
|1245    |NULL       | NULL     | No   | 11-04-2022|
|4266    |Drew       | Bob      | Yes  | 10-03-2022|
```

Comment: I'm not well-versed in spark, but you can left join the result onto itself by the ID and then replace the nulls via COALESCE. Here's how I would do it in SQL (I don't know Spark syntax, sorry): `SELECT a.ID, COALESCE(b.FirstName, a.FirstName) AS FirstName, COALESCE(b.LastName, a.LastName) AS LastName, a.Login, a.Date FROM Logins a LEFT OUTER JOIN Logins b ON a.ID = b.ID` 

This will check if the FirstName/LastName is null and return the first non-null value.

Answer (score 1):

I had filtered the df for non null names and tried to join it back to the original df and get the **name** columns that don't have null.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,["ID","FirstName","LastName","Login","Date"])

nameDf=df\
.filter("FirstName is not null or LastName is not null")\
.selectExpr("id as nameDf_ID","FirstName as nameDf_FirstName","LastName as nameDf_LastName")\
.distinct()

df.join(nameDf,df.ID==nameDf.nameDf_ID)\
.selectExpr("ID","nameDf_FirstName as FirstName","nameDf_LastName as LastName","Login","Date")\
.show()
```

```
+----+---------+--------+-----+----------+
|  ID|FirstName|LastName|Login|      Date|
+----+---------+--------+-----+----------+
|1245|     Matt|  Carter|  Yes|12-03-2022|
|1245|     Matt|  Carter|   No|11-04-2022|
|2344|    Emily|   Seuss|  Yes|12-01-2022|
|4266|     Drew|     Bob|  Yes|10-03-2022|
+----+---------+--------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dataframe that can serve as a lookup for the names against a specific ID. You can do that by filtering only non-NULL values of names like the previous answer.

```
names = df.filter(FirstName.isNotNull || LastName.isNotNull)
```

You can then use the names dataframe to fill out the NULL names in the original dataframe.

```
df.as("original").join(name.as("names"), Seq("ID"))
.select($"ID",
  coalesce($"original.FirstName", $"names.FirstName").as("FirstName"),
  coalesce($"original.LastName", $"names.LastName").as("LastName"),
  $"original.Login",
  $"original.Date"
)
```

`coalesce` results in selecting the first value and defaulting to the second value if the first one is null.